# Increasing value of array element

Tags: c, arrays

**Task:**

- Prompt user to enter 10 survey marks
- Categorise them based on the response (good, excellent..etc)

**Problem:**
- My end result shows some weird negative number
[image]
**Code:**

```
int marks[10], sum = 0, range[5];

printf("Enter the survey marks for the 10 questions:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    scanf("%d", &marks[i]);
    sum += marks[i];
    if (marks[i] == 0){
        range[0] += 1;
    }
    else if (marks[i] == 1){
        range[1] += 1;
    }
    else if (marks[i] == 2){
        range[2] += 1;
    }
    else if (marks[i] == 3){
        range[3] += 1;
    }
    else{
        range[4] += 1;
    }
}

printf("Response\tfrequency\n");
printf("--------\t---------\n");
printf("0-Very Bad\t%5d\n", range[0]);
printf("1-Bad\t\t%5d\n", range[1]);
printf("2-Good\t\t%5d\n", range[2]);
printf("3-Very Good\t%5d\n", range[3]);
printf("4-Excellent\t%5d\n\n", range[4]);

printf("Total mark = %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: Now think of a way to eliminate the if-else chain.

Comment: @stark Based on what I've learned till now, I can't think of any methods I can omptimise it with. Any tips you can share?

Comment: Note the similarity of `marks[I]` to the index into`range`. Does that suggest anything?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xtqTjCcc
@stark is this the right way?

Comment: Just made another for loop for it. but it still checks 5 times inside the loop. Is that any efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Uhh, just had to initialize my range to 0.

```
range[5] = { 0 }
```

Worked afterwards **lol**.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all the elements of array to zero. You have garbage values in array.
Like this:-

```
   int range[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
```